# "Bare with me" isn't a thing, yet it's used all over

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

Somewhere in the  [339 questions containing "bare with me"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bare+with+me%22) there may be one or two *intentional* uses of "bare" instead of "bear", but for the most part it's 339 post accidentally asking us all to get naked and answer programming questions.

We should probably whittle away at them over time and either...

- edit them to use the correct "bear with me"
- remove the phrase and the sentence that contains it altogether, as it's usually the kind of fluffy preamble that just takes up space, ie

  > bare with me, but I'm a noob and I have this really tough question that I've been stuck on for days

Bonus: The presence of "bare with me" seems to be a good indicator for low-quality questions and answers. I haven't edited one yet where "bare with me" was the *only* problem with the post.

Extra credit: There are [a lot of "alot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=alot) posts. A *lot*. Just saying.

Comment: Now, I know why [Is it “bear” or “bare” with me?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/is-it-bear-or-bare-with-me) has nearly 2,000,000 views on EL&U.

Answer (score 29):

I just found this post today, over 6 years later.

I noticed this pattern on my own approximately 18 months ago. At the time, if memory serves, there were over 3600 such requests for gratuitous nudity. Since then, mostly in spare moments during dull meetings, I have been slowly knocking down the list.

As of today there are [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bare+with+me%22).

---

Some observations I've made during this process:

Using a bot (as has now been suggested by two different commentators) would not have been very effective. While it could have corrected the simple spelling mistake, as one might imagine, users who make this class of spelling mistake usually make many other spelling and grammatical mistakes as well.

Perhaps more important, "Bear with me" almost always points to a phrase that adds not value to a post whatsoever. I estimate that 49 times out of 50, the proper edit was simply to remove the sentence which contained "Bear with me."  Some common examples:

- "I'm new to JavaScript, so bear with me"
- "Bear with me, I'm new to StackOverflow"
- "This post is long, so bear with me"

In about half the cases, these fluff phrases were accompanied by many other fluff phrases that I also deleted ("I've been at this for hours!" or "I have experience with [other, unrelated technology]")

In very rare cases, did I simply correct the spelling, and then, usually in an answer, not a question.

This exercise proved useful in bringing many ancient questions up to current site standards in other ways, too:

1. Improved titles (many old questions have titles that trigger the "Title cannot contain" rules)
2. Improved example URLs (Links like **mydomain.com** are no longer permitted--I updated to **example.com**)
3. Pastebin links without code blocks are no longer permitted, so I copied pastebin code into the questions, where possible
4. Lots of random spelling and grammar improvements (who knew so many people don't capitalize "I"?)

Some might (in fact, have, in comments on the question above) argue it was a waste of time, or an opportunity cost. That may be. But most of this effort happened when I needed a brainless activity to keep me from falling asleep while my boss was droning on about things like TPS reports and cover sheets. So I don't consider it a loss of time. If anything, consider it a redemption of boring meetings. :)

Comment: Now the link returns one :)

Comment: @Rubén: Bare with me while I fix that... :P

Comment: Thanks for the unexpected bonus, @ShadowTheCoffeeWizard

Comment: Since you visited AD once,  https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22bare+with+me%22

Comment: @ankii: Why don't you tackle that one? You can do it a lot faster than me, since your edits don't need to be reviewed :)

Comment: Doing 2 in a day :)

Comment: @ankii: With only 5 such questions, you should be able to do all of them in under 10 minutes.

Comment: But it bumps them on the home page. MacOS and iOS updates brought in a lot of questions. Will do the rest soon.